# Hide Navigationcontroller When swipe in XIB files

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, xib

**EDIT**
I think my problem is that I add the views as subviews in the same view, thats why I can't remove it ?

Im trying to learn swiping between views using XIB.
My storyboard contains 3 views
[image]

-Login

-Create Account

-View with scrollview that scrolls between a tableview and a blank view. This view has an embedded navigation controller (Editor -> Embed In -> Navigation Controller) 
[image]

I Don't want the navigation controller to be shown in my blank page.
I have created the tableView Controller and the blank UIControllerView by adding them as "addChildViewController", See code below

```
import UIKit

class MasterViewForScroll: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!

let Inbox : FriendlistTableBarView = FriendlistTableBarView(nibName: "FriendlistTableBarView", bundle: nil)
let Camera : CameraViewController = CameraViewController(nibName: "CameraViewController", bundle: nil)

func creatingSubViews() {

    self.addChildViewController(Inbox)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(Inbox.view)
    Inbox.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    Inbox.navigationController?.navigationBar.hidden = false

    var CameraView = Camera.view.frame
    CameraView.origin.x = self.view.frame.width
    Camera.view.frame = CameraView




    self.addChildViewController(Camera)
    self.scrollView.addSubview(Camera.view)
    Camera.didMoveToParentViewController(self)
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.view.frame.width * 2, self.view.frame.height)
}

   override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    creatingSubViews()
}
```

So my question is: How do I hide the navigation controller in the "Camera" view.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In your CameraViewController class, add the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad() 

    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = true   
}
```

Next, in your FriendlistTableBarView class (I guess it is a UIViewController subclass), add the following code:

```
override func viewWillAppear() {
    super.viewWillAppear()

    self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden = false  
}
```

So, when you swipe to the right - navigation bar will hide, and when you swipe to the left - it will appear again.

Comment: No :( didn't work. I think its because the tableview(friendliest) and the UIViewcontroller(blank page) share the same UIViewController(main). and that the main have navigation controller.